# Coins fast in Clash Of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to know how to get coins much faster in clash of clans WITHOUT using gems. I want to be able to upgrade my gold storages so I can repair my Clan Castle but I don't have enough coins. Any tips on how to get coins much faster???

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few ways to get gold faster in Clash of Clans. Here are all of your options (including gemming):

- Upgrade your gold collectors. Depending on the level of your Town Hall, you will only be able to upgrade your collectors to a certain level.
- Gem your gold collectors. By spending 9 gems on each collector, that collector will generate twice as much gold during the next 24 hours.
- Purchase gold directly from the shop. This is done with gems but is extremely costly. If you want to use gems to generate more gold, just boost your collectors unless you are extremely impatient.
- Raid other bases for their gold. Create an army and attack other bases in order to steal some of their gold. Note that as soon as you attack, you remove whatever shield you had at that point and become vulnerable to attack.

Comment: It should be noted that you can safely attack the single-player goblin camps without any consequences to your shield. They probably won't provide as much gold as another player might, but the amount of resources you can get is clearly displayed.